# Java Development Kit installer won't run after a reboot windows 10 crash during installation

Tags: windows-10, java

During a JDK(Java Development Kit) 8 installation Win 10 Crashed and now when I double click on JDK installer nothing appears.
I tried to install version 7 and all is OK but 8 won't run. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I have to delete programdata\java folder that contains corrupted installer extracted files then reinstall it!